# Issue with FB Javascript login SDK

Tags: javascript, oauth, sdk

My FB login works almost fine. The only problem is when i log in the first time, the response status === unknown. de popup closes and there is no redirect because the status is unknown, ok.. the second login attempt i press the fb login button, popup opens and closes again and the redirect take place. in the browser there are 2 fbsr_{appid} cookies. and then the status === connected.

```
function fblogin() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '{ my app id }',
  cookie     : true, 
  xfbml      : true,  
  version    : 'v3.2'
});

FB.login(function (response) {

        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 'connected') {  
            
        FB.api('/me',  { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'email,first_name,last_name,id' },
        function (response) {

              window.location.href = '/page_to_redirect_to?UserNAME=' + response.first_name + '%20' + response.last_name + '&UserEMAIL=' + response.email  + '&UserID=' + response.id;

        });
    }
}, {scope: 'email'});
}


 (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  <button onclick="fbLogin();" class="fb connect">Sign in with Facebook</button>
```

Comment: Are you testing this in a browser that might apply some “extended privacy” mode / tracker protection by default, such as Firefox?

Comment: i use chrome without extra privacy settings

Comment: Does anything change, if you initialize the SDK with `status: true`?

Comment: I have similar issue, the facebook login was working great for 2 years already and now every first login returns empty response. Any suggestions?

Comment: Status : true .. unfortunately no difference CBroe!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v10.0) the `unknown` status happens when FB can't confirm whether the user is logged in and gave permissions to your app. So it looks like this can be a normal situation to receive that status, and the user should try to log in again.

Another thing is why do you always get this `unknown` status in your first request. Not sure why this is happening.

By the way - I think you're using an old version of the Facebook API. (currently v10 is newest)

Comment: I think that is referring to an unknown status determined some other way than by calling `FB.login` though (and it specifically mentions the `canvas` app environment.)